# in adding values from different fields and add them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've an issue which is that i've 4 radiobuttons for one service and when user selects any radio button its value is added to total_sum using javascript .change() function. But the problem is it keeps adding false value. Like if you select two radio boxes each at a time. Then it adds false value

```js
jQuery("input:radio").change(function() {
  var total = parseInt(jQuery('#total_sum').val());
  var ischecked= jQuery(this).is(':checked');
  var unchecked = jQuery(this).is(':unchecked');
  var price = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
  var newprice = total;
  var sum = 0;
  if(ischecked){
    sum = total + Number(price);
    jQuery('#total_sum').val(sum);
  }
  else if(unchecked){}
});
var total = parseInt(jQuery('#total_sum').val());
jQuery('#sqfootage').bind('change', function () {
  var sqfootage = jQuery('#sqfootage').val();
  var sqfootage_val = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  if(sqfootage >= 1 && sqfootage <= 1500)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 10;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 1501 && sqfootage <= 1800)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 15;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 1801 && sqfootage <= 2100)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 20;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 2101 && sqfootage <= 2400)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 25;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 2401 && sqfootage <= 2700)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 30;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 2701 && sqfootage <= 3000)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 35;
  }
  else if(sqfootage >= 3001 && sqfootage <= 3300)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 40;
  }
  else if(sqfootage > 3300)
  { 
    sqfootage_val = 40;
  }
  sum = total + Number(sqfootage_val);
  jQuery('#total_sum').val(sum);         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quest fl">
  <legend>What is the total square footage?</legend>

  <div class="one_col">
    <input name="sqfootage" id="sqfootage" min="1"  type="number" value="" placeholder="SqFootage:">
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="quest fl">
  <legend>Services</legend>
  <div class="one_col">
    <label><input name="service1" value="10" vt="Standard (one time)" type="radio" i="0">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
    <label><input name="service2" value="20" vt="Standard (one time)" type="radio" i="0">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
    <label><input name="service3" value="25" vt="Standard (one time)" type="radio" i="0">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
    <label><input name="service4" value="30" vt="Standard (one time)" type="radio" i="0">4</label>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="total_sum" name="total_sum" class="medium" type="text" value="89">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has error. jQuery does not include a :unchecked selector. Instead, you need to invert the `:checked` selector. So change

`var unchecked = jQuery(this).is(':unchecked');`

to `var unchecked = jQuery(this).not(':checked');`

to fix the issue. Not sure though why you are using radio instead of checkboxes.

Comment: yes this is it. And since `unchecked` is not really used in code, commenting it removes `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: unchecked` and lets the code continue executing

Comment: and regarding radio, you should take Hector advice. Checkboxes are better for your case. and no need to use two variables (`checked` and `unchecked`). Use only one boolean variable. use also `var $this=jQuery(this)` for caching.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply guys. I appreciate the answer but unchecked is not the problem that i've asked for. See in code i haven't anything under unchecked condition

Comment: And not sure why OP is checking `checked` and `unchecked` on the same element.

Comment: the problem is this

For example
if i select one radio button(it adds 10 + total(89) = 99)
but what if i decide to choose another radio(it gets total which was 99 and adds 20 into 99 which 119)

Comment: @user2233501 Unless you fix this error your code will not execute.

Comment: What is the expected behavior when you select second radio?

Comment: @HectorBarbossa it adds value to total amount (89). for example if i select one radio it add its value 10 to total and total becomes 99. But if tend to choose another radio it adds the value to new total (99). I dont want this to happen what i want is it should add value of selected radio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117150/discussion-between-user2233501-and-hector-barbossa).

Answer (score 1):

There is no jQuery pseudoselector ':unchecked'

You want this line instead:

`var unchecked = jQuery(this).not(':checked');`

I ran this in jsFiddle and it works after fixing this error.